# Prerequisites for Griffiths electrodynamics

Tags: electromagnetism, resource-recommendations, soft-question, classical-electrodynamics, education

I want to start reading Griffiths [electrodynamics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism) during my holidays. But I am not sure of the math I need to know to start reading and understand the text thoroughly. So any advice would be thoroughly appreciated.

Comment: Griffith's first chapter is devoted entirely to the mathematics required for the book (which is more-or-less [multivariate calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariable_calculus))

Comment: I have read griffiths math chapters but I'm not happy with them. I am asking for proper math textbooks

Comment: You have to know [vector calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus).

Comment: If you're not happy with Griffith's first chapter, then you are not going to be happy with his textbook, as he uses the math from that section throughout his book (hence including it in there).

Comment: Can you get through "Div, Grad, Curl, and all that". Griffith uses nice symmetries and angles, values, etc. in the examples and problems. I was able to do the whole book (for a friend considering it for a course) without putting pencil to paper, and I'm no math wizard.

Answer (score 2):

Go through the first math chapter in the textbook and everything you do not understand look up online or, my recomendation, in [this](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mathematical-Methods-Physics-Engineering-Comprehensive/dp/0521679710) textbook. The textbook is really good and covers everything you will ever need in undergrad studies.

Answer (score 1):

Boyce and DiPrima's Elementary Differential Equations should be enough.
You could also try Kreyszig's Advanced Engineering Mathematics, although the whole book is not necessary.

Comment: I think Boyce DiPrima is overkill, unless you've got time enough.